# Parent table cannot be updated when foreign key is present

Tags: mysql

There are two tables one is a parent i.e., groups table which has foreign key to a child table i.e., users. I am not able to edit foreign key column in parent table where as I have given it to cascade to child table. It gives a error as follows:

```
Error Code : 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tms`.`groups`, CONSTRAINT `FK_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupName`) REFERENCES `users` (`groupname`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Thanks,
  -Jeevan

Comment: show us the table structure and the query

Comment: Can you share more details like the query used etc?

Answer (score 1):

I assume a group contains many users, and a users belongs to one group.

Then you have declared the foreign key in the wrong direction. Actually `users.groupname` must reference `tms.groups`. Drop the current foreign key and rebuild it the other way around (in the `users` table).

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you try to reference a non existing entry in database. In short, you inserted into `groups` and tried to reference an `user` entry which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: what I am willing to ask is does the foreign key cascade to users table if I modify the name in groups table i.e., parent table in relationship?

Comment: Oh, you tried to update the value of the foreign key. No, that isn't possible. The foreign key can only reference an existing entry in the referenced table. But changing the value of the fk doesn't change the value of the referenced table column! `ON UPDATE CASCADE` just means, that the value of the foreign key constraint will be updated, in case that the value of the referenced table column is updated. Similar it's with `ON DELETE CASCADE` for deleting a referenced data row.